# Pass an object to angularjs template from jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pug

I am trying to pass an object from the node to the client like below

```
render: function(req,res){
    res.render('auth',{
        userData : req.session.user
    });
  }
```

In my auth.jade the code is as below

```
script.
    var data = !{JSON.stringify(userData)}
    console.log(data)
    window.top.location='/profile'
```

So I am redirecting the application to a new route which I have defined in the routeProvider using angularjs

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      })
```

So is there a way by which I can access the 'data' object in the controller for that route?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this into your script:

```
var data = !{JSON.stringify(userData)};
window.serverData= data;
```

After in your app.js, you can do this:

```
app.value('serverData', window.serverData);
```

And in your controller:

```
app.controller('controllerName', ['serverData', function(serverData){

console.log(serverData);

}]);
```

You can access to window var into the controller without doing app.value, but it is a good practice.